# Do the new macbook pro models (2011) still have a 4 partition limit?

Tags: mac, startup, partition, unix

If I remember correctly, the older Macbook pro models (pre 2011) had a 4 partition limit: so, if you tried to install multiple operating systems, you had this limit.

Do the new models (2011) still have this limitation? I'm planning to install two Linuxes, A Windows and a Mac partitions to boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a limitation of the hardware. This is a limitation of the [MBR partitioning scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record) required to allow Windows to boot with other non-Windows operating systems. The MBR partitioning scheme only supports 4 primary partitions.

The [GUID partitioning scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) that Mac OS X uses by default is able to handle more that 4 partitions but [not all operating systems support GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#OS_support_of_GPT).

Comment: So, I'm stuck on 4 partitions only if using windows... right?

Comment: If Windows 7 can boot from a GPT partition formatted as FAT32 or NTFS on a Mac (not something I've tried) then no. You can create as many GPT partitions as you like.

Comment: Well, it seems from the link you posted that Windows 7 64 bit can Boot from GPT on EFI, I need to read all these links completely to see the caveats of these approaches.

Comment: An interesting link about GPT and ubuntu on a mac: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-782803.html